# No feedback after pressing React native onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-shared-element, react-navigation-shared-element

I have a button component with a simple onPress

```
const Press = () => {

    return (
        <Button
            onPress={() => {
                Alert.alert('You tapped the button!');
            }}
            title="Press Me"
        />
    )

}
```

which i then import in another component as < Press /> but the onPress function doesn't work, whether as an alert, console.log or navigate function

```
const Anothercomp = (props: any) => {
const { item, index, scrollX } = props;
  const inputRange = [(index - 1) * width, index * width, (index + 1) * width];
  const scale = scrollX.interpolate({
    inputRange,
    outputRange: [0.4, 1, 0.4],
    extrapolate: "clamp"
  });

  const postion = scrollX.interpolate({
    inputRange,
    outputRange: [-230, 1, 0],
    extrapolate: "clamp"
  });
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        width,
        marginTop: 40,
        alignItems: "center"
      }}
    >
      <SharedElement id={`item.${item.id}.photo`}>
        <Animated.Image
          source={item.image}
          style={[
            styles.imageContainer,
            {
              transform: [
                {
                  scale
                }
              ],
              marginLeft: postion
            }
          ]}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
      </SharedElement>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          alignItems: "center",
          borderRadius: 20,
          padding: 15,
          width: width - 70,
        }}
      >
       <View
          style={{
            marginTop: 10,
            flexDirection: "row",
            alignItems: "center"
          }}
        >
            <Press/>
            <View style={styles.add} >
              <Typography color="#ccc" text="-" size={18} />
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I have tried to use react-native-gesture-handler as shown below but still nothing happens

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text, Alert} from 'react-native'
import { Gesture, GestureDetector } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const Press = () => {
    const singleTap = Gesture.Tap()
  .maxDuration(250)
  .onStart(() => {
    Alert.alert('Single tap!');
  });

const doubleTap = Gesture.Tap()
  .maxDuration(250)
  .onStart(() => {
    Alert.alert('Double tap!');
  });

return (
  <GestureDetector gesture={Gesture.Exclusive(doubleTap, singleTap)}>
    <Text>gesture</Text>
  </GestureDetector>
)}

export default Press
```

Full source code can be found here https://snack.expo.dev/@umarabdullahi/234foods

react-native-shared-element and react-navigation-shared-element are the packages i am experimenting with, can they cause this?

If you're going through the snack, the function is at src/components/Press.tsx this is then called in src/components/FoodItem.tsx which is in turn called from src/screens/Details.tsx

[image: click on any of the circled links]

[image: the button I have issues with is circled here]

Comment: You currently provided code works for me. The onPress function of your Press component is triggered as expected.

Comment: Does it render the Alert function on your device? If yes, are you on ios, android or the expo simulator. Still doesn't work on my end

Comment: It doesnt work in the web as expected but it does work on a real device (I have used an iPhone 12).  Here is a version of your [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/234foods) that changes the items under the search bar to your Press component.

Comment: Your Press onPress is working - add a Press component to your homepage in your snack with a console.log() in the onPress and you'll be able to see it on click (click in the bottom left, where it says 'x errors, x warnings' to open the logs). Is it a particular Press that isn't working for you? do you at least see console logs?

Comment: Wrong function, the press function I have an issue with is located at src/components/Press.tsx this is then called in src/components/FoodItem.tsx which is in turn called from src/screens/Details.tsx

Comment: My question has been edited and screenshots added to provide clarity

Answer (score 0):

Press log something on your onPress method and check is it work. It can be a different problem.

Comment: Wrong function, the press function I have an issue with is located at src/components/Press.tsx this is then called in src/components/FoodItem.tsx which is in turn called from src/screens/Details.tsx

Comment: My question has been edited and screenshots added to provide clarity

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to run the code on my device and it seems to work fine.
As the others have already mentioned try to print out a console.log() and share the error, it might be that the problem is related to a different issue.

Comment: Wrong function, the press function I have an issue with is located at src/components/Press.tsx this is then called in src/components/FoodItem.tsx which is in turn called from src/screens/Details.tsx

Comment: My question has been edited and screenshots added to provide clarity

Answer (score 0):

The style of the following after `<Press/>` is not visible. Is it possible that it has an absolute position and actually overlaps the button and so cancels its `onPress` function?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not your `Press` component or the `onPress` function.

Your issue is located in `FoodItem`. You are creating a `View` with position `absolute` and a fixed `height` at the bottom of the container which causes your `Press` component (and every other component that overlaps with the absolute positioned view) to be placed behind this view. All touch events will be captured by the `View` which is supposed to be the orange background.

Hence, the root cause is the following view in `FoodItem`.

```js
 <View style={[styles.bottom, { backgroundColor: item.color }]} />
```

The easiest solution would be to provide a higher `zIndex` for the view that contains the pressable components or in this case it is sufficient to add a negative `zIndex` to `styles.bottom.

```js
bottom: {
    width,
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    height: "70%",
    zIndex: -10
  },
```

[Here is an updated snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/absolute-position-problem). Notice that I have only tested this on Android.